# Colon and array and namespace in TCL

Tags: arrays, namespaces, tcl

I'm a beginner in TCL.
I've found a variable assignement like this:

```
set ::C0::B0::B1(A:input:signal)  "P0"
```

I know that B1 is in the namespace of B0, that is in the name space of C0, and B1 is an array.
What I don't undestand is the sintax  `B1(A:input:signal)`?
Can you halp me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array *element* names are arbitrary strings, which can have any internal structure that you and/or the application which them to have. Putting parentheses in element names can be a little bit awkward syntactically, but it's just a syntax thing (the `$` syntax is a bit restrictive relative to what Tcl's variable model supports); if the element name is itself taken from a variable then it really can be anything at all. For example:

```
set foo "a(b)c"
set bar($foo) 123
```

You can even use spaces or binary data as element names.

In your case, the array name is `::C0::B0::B1` (`B1` in the namespace `::C0::B0`, as you know) and the element name is `A:input:signal`; the internal colons in the element name have no special meaning to Tcl, no more than the `A` or `input` do. Other code looking at that array may have different ideas about that, of course.